# How to standardization in spectrogram

Tags: python, signal-processing

I am training a CNN by spectrogram. 
I have read a paper that said that the spectrogram should be standardization before feeding to CNN. In some tutorials on the internet, They standard in feature vectors.

I.e: Each sample in my dataset described by 10 features. So the training set is [n, 10] and they will standardize in [n, 0], [n, 1] and so on.

But I see in some lectures they normalize spectrogram in all elements (calculate mean and std in all elements not only in a row).

I.e: if spectrogram have n x m dimension and they standardized with each element in m x n matrix we transform using [this formula](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/z-score/).

I don't know what techniques are correct, and how can I apply z-score to normalize in the multi-dimension array (ie RGB image, RGBA image, ..)

Sorry if my question has some grammar mistakes because my English is not good.

Answer (score 0):

z-score normalization or feature standardization should be done for features, which means for all features seperately. Imagine you have an eeg signal with 8 channels and your features are variance and root mean square for all data in each channel. So you have two feature vectors with 8 elements which the range of their values are different. Thus it's reasonable to normalize these two vectors seperately with their own mean and std.